# Mdx union between different dimensions

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, union, mdx, ssas-tabular

I have situation where I have two different dimensions in a model. Dimension A has ColorId, FirstColor and SecondColor. Dimension B has ColorId and Firstcolor. I am trying to get a complete list of colorIds from both dimensions that are distinct. Please keep in mind that this mdx needs to be used in ssrs.

**Dimension A**

```
ColorId     FirstColor    SecondColor
T0z17       Blue           Green
T0lqa       Red            Yellow
```

**Dimension B**

```
ColorId     FirstColor
T201k       Black
Tph1v       Orange
```

**Intended Output (only 1 column)**

```
ColorId
T0z17
T0lqa
T201k
Tph1v
```

Comment: It's a very uncommon task for SSAS. The idea behind OLAP is to provide dimension with distinct values only. It's possible, but the easiest way to do so is to get the result from DWH using SQL querying.

Comment: To be clear you expect the same color to appear in Dimension A and in Dimension B?

Comment: @greggalloway No it doesn't necessarily have to have the same color. Just the column names and data types. Color ID will be in the same format as well

Comment: @Danylo Korostil Any way of doing this in ssrs? I would prefer not to add a separate dimension just for this. I can't use sql query since for our requirement we can only use the tabular model. Prefer to use ssrs or mdx

Comment: I'm not a SSRS expert, but most likely you have to create two datasets (A, B dimensions values) and reuse the Lookup() function there as join alternative. Then get distinct values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Greg's answer isn't real distinct, I'd fix his code in the following way:

```
With 
Member [Measures].[SameColor] as
IIF(
    [Dimension A].[Color Id].CurrentMember.Name = [Dimension B].[Color Id].CurrentMember.Name,
    1,
    NULL
)

Member [Measures].[OnlyAColor] as
IIF(
    IsEmpty(
        LinkMember(
            [Dimension A].[Color Id].CurrentMember,
            [Dimension B].[Color Id]
        )
    ),
    1,
    NULL
)

Member [Measures].[OnlyBColor] as
IIF(
    IsEmpty(
        LinkMember(
            [Dimension B].[Color Id].CurrentMember,
            [Dimension A].[Color Id]
        )
    ),
    1,
    NULL
)

Member [Measures].[Color] as 
IIF(
    [Dimension A].[Color Id].CurrentMember is [Dimension A].[Color Id].[All],
    [Dimension B].[Color Id].CurrentMember.Name
    [Dimension A].[Color Id].CurrentMember.Name
)

Select [Measures].[Color] on 0,  
NonEmpty(
    [Dimension A].[Color Id].[Color Id].Members * [Dimension B].[Color Id].[Color Id].Members,
    [Measures].[SameColor]
)
+
NonEmpty(
    [Dimension A].[Color Id].[Color Id].Members * [Dimension B].[Color Id].[All],
    [Measures].[OnlyAColor]
)
+
NonEmpty(
    [Dimension A].[Color Id].[All] * [Dimension B].[Color Id].[Color Id].Members,
    [Measures].[OnlyBColor]
) on 1
From [YourCube]
```

Comment: if Dim A and Dim B have used different key values for the colors so Red is key 101 in A but 102 in B (entirely possible) then `LinkMember` will not work

Comment: Yeah, you're right. You can reuse the StrToMember() function with names in that case. We don't know, I just wanted to make a point about distinct logic.

Comment: (upped) I really like the `NonEmpty(....,[Measures].[SameColor])` trick for de-duping.

Answer (score 3):

Try this union query:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Color] as 
   IIf(
     [Dimension A].[Color Id].CurrentMember 
        Is [Dimension A].[Color Id].[All]
   , [Dimension B].[Color Id].CurrentMember.Name
   , [Dimension A].[Color Id].CurrentMember.Name
   )
SELECT [Measures].[Color] on 0,
{
 [Dimension A].[Color Id].[Color Id].Members
 * [Dimension B].[Color Id].[All]
}
+
{
 [Dimension A].[Color Id].[All]
 * [Dimension B].[Color Id].[Color Id].Members
}
On 1
FROM [YourCube]
```

Comment: Nice, but it will result duplicates, not distinct values.

Comment: I've reused Greg's code and added a distinct concept.

Comment: @Danylo - the `+` operator removes duplicates when performing a union

Comment: @whytheq interesting. Didn't know that. Unfortunately it won't dedup across dimensions. Luckily Mutai clarified deduping wasn't necessary.

Comment: @whytheq {[Dimension A].[Color Id].[Black] * [Dimension B].[Color Id].[All]} + {[Dimension A].[Color Id].[All] * [Dimension B].[Color Id].[Black]} will return two Black members.

Comment: @DanyloKorostil true - my mistake - it de-dupes but not across a two dimensional tuples as in this script